# Separating embedded document from original in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

Mongo's aggregation framework and the `$lookup` keyword allows one to merge documents that have a relationship between them. For example, I might have a many - to - many relationship of authors and books. In the following example, the first book is written by the first two authors, and the second book is written by the third author.

```js
> db.books.find().pretty()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ec"),
    title: '300 years of peanut juggling: A longitudinal analysis.',
    inPrint: true,
    authors: [
      ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6e9"),
      ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6ea")
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ed"),
    title: "Mystery Overflow: murder and chaos on the Web's biggest developer Q & A platform.",
    inPrint: true,
    authors: [ ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6eb") ],
    edition: 2
  }
]
> db.authors.find().pretty()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6e9"),
    name: 'Jason Filippou',
    age: 33,
    nationalities: [ 'GRC, CND' ],
    books: [ ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ec") ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6ea"),
    name: 'Mary Chou',
    age: 39,
    nationalities: [ 'USA' ],
    books: [ ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ec") ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6eb"),
    name: 'Max Schwarz',
    age: 42,
    job: 'pilot',
    books: [ ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ed") ]
  }
]
```

I can execute:

```js
> db.books.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "authors", localField: "authors", foreignField: "_id", as: "copyOfAuthorData"}}])
```

And I get:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ec"),
    title: '300 years of peanut juggling: A longitudinal analysis.',
    inPrint: true,
    authors: [
      ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6e9"),
      ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6ea")
    ],
    copyOfAuthorData: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6e9"),
        name: 'Jason Filippou',
        age: 33,
        nationalities: [ 'GRC, CND' ],
        books: [ ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ec") ]
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6ea"),
        name: 'Mary Chou',
        age: 39,
        nationalities: [ 'USA' ],
        books: [ ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ec") ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ed"),
    title: "Mystery Overflow: murder and chaos on the Web's biggest developer Q & A platform.",
    inPrint: true,
    authors: [ ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6eb") ],
    edition: 2,
    copyOfAuthorData: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("60a673c44312c6d8ea7bd6eb"),
        name: 'Max Schwarz',
        age: 42,
        job: 'pilot',
        books: [ ObjectId("60a676f24312c6d8ea7bd6ed") ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do the opposite operation. That is to say, transform an array field of JSON objects to an array field of `ObjectID`s that are foreign keys to the `_id` field of a freshly made document. This could make the original documents lighter and allows for changing the modeling of our data on the fly, as per dynamic application requirements.

Comment: Little bit confused, can you show that how you need to do and expected output?

Comment: Sure, the expected output would be the reverse of what I have above. You would begin from the output of `db.books.aggregate()` and you end up with two separate documents.

Comment: Can you elaborate more by editing the question and what are the two separate documents you aare expecting,

Comment: To transform the resulting documents you can use _projection_, typically using the `$addFields` or `$project` stages.